Laravel filament issue in showing image in edit and view pages
I am new to laravel filament. I have a user resource where there is an image for the user the picture is showing in the table (list page) and I can edit and update it and it is correctly changing in the database but when I enter the edit or view page in filament I can't see it!
below the code and images of whats happening.
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Resources;

use App\Filament\Resources\UserResource\Pages;
use App\Models\User;
use Filament\Forms;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Resources\Resource;
use Filament\Tables;
use Filament\Tables\Table;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletingScope;

class UserResource extends Resource
{
    protected static ?string $model = User::class;

    protected static ?string $navigationIcon = 'heroicon-o-rectangle-stack';

    public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('first_name')
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('last_name')
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('email')
                    ->email()
                    ->required()
                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('country_code')
                    ->maxLength(255)
                    ->default('971')
                    ->readOnly(),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('phone_number')
                    ->tel()
                    ->maxLength(255),
//                Forms\Components\DateTimePicker::make('email_verified_at'),
//                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('password')
//                    ->password()
//                    ->required()
//                    ->maxLength(255),
                Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('image')
                    ->image()
                    ->directory('users'),
                Forms\Components\Hidden::make('company_role_id')
                    ->default(2)
                    ->afterStateHydrated(function ($set, $state, $record) {
                        if (!$state) {
                            $set('company_role_id', 2);
                        }
                    }),
                Forms\Components\TextInput::make('company_role')
                    ->default('Share Holder')
                    ->label('Company Role')
                    ->afterStateHydrated(function ($set, $state, $record) {
                        if (!$state) {
                            $set('company_role', 'Share Holder');
                        }
                    })
                    ->disabled(),
                Forms\Components\Select::make('companies')
                    ->label('Companies')
                    ->relationship('companies', 'name')
                    ->multiple()
                    ->preload(),
                Forms\Components\Hidden::make('full_name')
                    ->dehydrated(false),
            ]);
    }

    public static function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->columns([
                Tables\Columns\ImageColumn::make('image')->circular(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('first_name')
                    ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('last_name')
                    ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('email')
                    ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('country_code')
                    ->searchable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('phone_number')
                    ->searchable(),
//                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('email_verified_at')
//                    ->dateTime()
//                    ->sortable(),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('created_at')
                    ->dateTime()
                    ->sortable()
                    ->toggleable(isToggledHiddenByDefault: true),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('updated_at')
                    ->dateTime()
                    ->sortable()
                    ->toggleable(isToggledHiddenByDefault: true),
                Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('companyRole.name')
                    ->label('Company Role'),
            ])
            ->filters([
                Tables\Filters\TrashedFilter::make(),
            ])
            ->actions([
                Tables\Actions\ViewAction::make(),
                Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
            ])
            ->bulkActions([
                Tables\Actions\BulkActionGroup::make([
                    Tables\Actions\DeleteBulkAction::make(),
                    Tables\Actions\ForceDeleteBulkAction::make(),
                    Tables\Actions\RestoreBulkAction::make(),
                ]),
            ]);
    }

    public static function getRelations(): array
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    public static function getPages(): array
    {
        return [
            'index' => Pages\ListUsers::route('/'),
            'create' => Pages\CreateUser::route('/create'),
            'view' => Pages\ViewUser::route('/{record}'),
            'edit' => Pages\EditUser::route('/{record}/edit'),
        ];
    }

    public static function getEloquentQuery(): Builder
    {
        return parent::getEloquentQuery()
            ->withoutGlobalScopes([
                SoftDeletingScope::class,
            ]);
    }
}





Hello
-> You can make use of filesysteams.php config for this.
-> first you have to create a disc inside filesysteams.php config like below
'disks' => [
    'user' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path('uploads/user'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/uploads/user',
    ],
 ]

-> you can add your desire path instead of 'upload/user' this will be where your all images will be stored.
-> now for form add below code
Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('image')
    ->disk('user')

-> in table view add below code
ImageColumn::make('image')
    ->disk('user')
    ->circular()

-> this should do the work, it works for edit and view as well.

but if use s3 does not work for me :( When inspect response on click edit get this ...,"image":[[],{"s":"arr"}], ...  I do not understand why image not loaded :(

try using : ->visibility('publico') ,  someone else had same problem and used this to work it correctly. make sure you add exactly i told you(publico not public). let me no if it works.

Where to add that?

add that in FileUpload  input like
Forms\Components\FileUpload::make('image')->disk('user')->visibility('publico')

It didn't work to me :(

Worked if I added ->visibility('private') and removed getter which gets images from s3.

that's great! up vote if comment was any helpful.
